# Can anybody help me to write this function in one line?

Tags: python

Here is my solution. It is not elegant. Please help.

```
def calculateHandlen(hand):
    """ 
    Returns the length (number of letters) in the current hand.

    hand: dictionary (string int)
    returns: integer
    """
    num = 0
    keyS = hand.keys()
    for key in keyS:
        if hand[key] > 0:
            num += hand[key]
    return num
```

Comment: Why do you need it in one line? What is wrong with a function?

Comment: Why?! This function is fine the way it is. Don't fall into the trap of thinking "one-liners" make for more elegant code.

Comment: How does "length (number of letters)" give you `if hand[key] > 0:`?

Comment: I'm torn here, because I'm 100% behind the idea of not golfing code unnecessarily.. but this is a case where if the code is doing what I think it's doing, I don't think it's fine, because it's far more complicated (note: not  *long*) than it needs to be.

Comment: Is `hand[key]` ever negative? If not, `sum(hand.values())`

Comment: I was busy writing up an answer when this got closed: https://notehub.org/1e9vz

Comment: This is true oneliner: `result = lambda x: sum([len(v) for k, v in x.items()])`. And You use it like this: `result(some_dict)`

Comment: @AlexHall Nice answer. Especial love the line by line explanations. Wish I could give you an up-vote somehow.

Answer (score 4):

```
def calculateHandlen(hand):
    return sum(v for v in hand.values() if v > 0)
```

But why?

Comment: I'm taking mit 6.00.1x   And somebody said he/she can do it in one line. But I don't believe it.  That's why. Thanks man!

Comment: @VatoLiu technically one liners in python are turing complete: you can do anything.